# MySQL PHP - substr() causing 0 zeros to be entered into database on empty form fields

Tags: php, mysql, database, substring

I am using `substr(trim('SOME_FORM_VALUE'),0,7),` on some form values just before submitting them to the database.

Form fields that have been submitted blank, are ending up as **0** *(ZERO)* in the database.
If I remove the **substr()** everything is fine and there is no value in the database. The database (InnoDB) column is set as **VARCHAR** and **not null**.

code example:

```
$data_Arr = array(
'SOME_TABLE_COLUMN1' => substr(trim('SOME_FORM_VALUE1'),0,7),
'SOME_TABLE_COLUMN2' => substr(trim('SOME_FORM_VALUE2'),0,50)
);

$this->db->update('SOME_TABLE', $data_Arr);
```

Last MySQL Query ends up looking like this:

```
INSERT INTO `SOME_TABLE` (`SOME_TABLE_COLUMN1`, `SOME_TABLE_COLUMN2`)
VALUES (0, 0);
```

- Why is **0** *(ZERO)* the result of substr() on an empty form string?
- Any idea how to prevent the  **0** *(ZERO)* from being entered?

Thanks all :)

Comment: Could you paste your code for inserting the value into the database? A `SHOW CREATE TABLE yourtable` would be nice, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used 'mb_strimwidth' - does NOT resolve to zero in the event of empty string.

```
<?php
echo mb_strimwidth("Hello World", 0, 10);
// outputs Hello W
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

[`substr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php):

> Returns the extracted part of string; **or FALSE on failure**, or an empty
>   string.

So you're probably getting the false value converted to 0 if you're attempting to return a portion of the string that is out of bounds.

Comment: Ah! Wish I would have thought of that :) Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @colin-morelli Does that work? Care to provide an example or add that to the answer... I'm looking at the strlen but not sure how that resolves it. Would the solution be to try to have the empty string as the result instead of FALSE?

Comment: It would be great if you could provide an example of the strlen() solution @Colin Morelli or add it to the answer?

Answer (score 1):

i think you could try using if to test before substr

```
   if (strlen($string) > 7){
    $file_name= substr(trim($string,0,$max)); 
   }
```